# 'compgen' appears to have undocumented parameter '--', can I rely on it being present across systems?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, shell-builtin, compatibility, compgen

I happen to be on *Ubuntu 18.04*, with *GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)*
The output of

```
% compgen -A file --
test-data
foobar
--
```

outputs all files/dirs in the current directory as though no token to complete was passed.  However, the call

```
% compgen -A file -- --
--
```

correctly outputs either nothing or `--`* depending upon whether or not there is actually a file/files  `--`* present.
(NOTE: Trying pass '--' using the '-W' parameter doesn't help.

The relevant [gnu man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) and [ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/bash.1.html) are identical -

> compgen [option] [word]
>
> Generate possible completion matches for word according to the options,  which  maybe any option accepted by the complete builtin with the exception of -p and -r, and write the matches to the standard output.  When using the -F  or  -C  options,  the various  shell  variables  set  by  the  programmable  completion facilities, while available, will not have useful values.
>
> The matches will be generated in the same way as  if  the  programmable  completion code  had  generated  them  directly  from a completion specification with the same flags.  If word  is  specified,  only  those  completions  matching  word  will  be displayed.
>
> The  return  value is true unless an invalid option is supplied, or no matches were generated.

It appears as though the `--` parameter works as an optional delimiter to show where the partial begins, but it is also interpreted as an 'illegal option` with regards to the return status.

It's easy enough to put in the extra `--` to work as a delimiter so that `--` is interpreted correctly, but can I rely on the `--` to always be required across different bash versions and/or linux (or unix) systems?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski   What is the definition of an 'option argument' in **"The first -- argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options."** ?    Depending on the meaning of 'option argument' is might expect `compgen -W -- -A file` or `compgen -X -- -A file` to work, but they don't. --- scrath that, `-W` and `-X` don't seem to be effective for `compgen` anyway.

Comment: [Definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_262). The `-W` option *requires* something just after; this is the option-argument for the option. The same for `-X`.